How to pass an array of pipable operators to pipe()?
[Angular 12]I have a service with a method, handleFormControlChanges, which accepts, a formControl, a destroy subject, a method and an array of pipable operators (e.g., delay), and I would like to apply them using pipe().
handleFormControlChanges<T>(
 formControl: FormControl,
 destroy$: Subject<void>,
 onValueChange: (value: T) => void,
 customOperators: Array<OperatorFunction<any, any>> = []
): void {

 formControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    ...customOperators,
    takeUntil(destroy$),
    tap(() => this.setLoading$(true))
  )
  .subscribe(onValueChange);
}

I can't just destructure an array like ...customOperators and pass it to pipe() as it causes this TypeScript error:
TS2575: No overload expects 2 arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 2 or 4 arguments.
How can I pass the array of pipable operators to pipe()? How can I avoid this error?

This question is similar to: RxJs: Can you spread operators as arguments into pipe operator. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Not really, as here we specify exactly which operators we want and pass them like a function using 'apply' with pipe.
My goal is an array of operators that can be very different from one another.
If I'm wrong, please correct me.

I linked a potential duplicate, but for your specific use case, I'd just loop through the custom operators to compose the overall observable:
handleFormControlChanges<T>(
  formControl: FormControl,
  destroy$: Subject<void>,
  onValueChange: (value: T) => void,
  customOperators: Array<OperatorFunction<any, any>> = []
): void {

  // Capture the initial observable.
  let composedChanges = formControl.valueChanges;

  // Apply each of the supplied custom operators.
  for (let op of customOperators) {
    composedChanges = composedChanges.pipe(op);
  }

  // Subscribe to the composed result.
  composedChanges
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(destroy$),
      tap(() => this.setLoading$(true))
    )
    .subscribe(onValueChange);
}

